# How can I make a website button open up an SMS compose to a phone number?

Tags: html

I've found solutions that make it so that when you click a button on a website, it links to a phone number and the users phone will open up the dialer with that number pre-filled like so.

What I want to do instead is open up the users sms application in "compose message" mode to that specific number. Is there any way to do this? I've tried the following approach, but it doesn't work on Android:

```
sms://1-516-400-6217
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The general format is:
`<a href="sms:+919999999999?body=Hello World!">Link</a>`

You could also add multiple numbers to the recipient list:
`<a href="sms:+919999999999,+919999999990?body=Hello World!">Link</a>`

I found this to be working on my Android device, as well:
`<a href="sms://+919999999999?body=Hello%20World!">Single recipient and encoded body</a>`

A Small Demo:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 24px;
}

code {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Run this Snippet on an actual mobile device to check if it supports the special links</h1>
  <hr>

  <pre><code>&lt;a href=&quot;sms:+919999999999?body=Hello World!&quot;&gt;Single recipient and plain body&lt;/a&gt;</code></pre>
  <a href="sms:+919999999999?body=Hello World!">Single recipient and plain body</a>

  <pre>
<br>
</pre>


  <pre><code>&lt;a href=&quot;sms:+919999999999,+919999999990?body=Hello World!&quot;&gt;Multile recipient and plain body&lt;/a&gt;</code></pre>
  <a href="sms:+919999999999,+919999999990?body=Hello World!">Multile recipient and plain body</a>

  <pre>
<br>
</pre>


  <pre><code>&lt;a href=&quot;sms://+919999999999?body=Hello%20World!&quot;&gt;Single recipient and encoded body&lt;/a&gt;</code></pre>
  <a href="sms://+919999999999?body=Hello%20World!">Single recipient and encoded body</a>
</body>
```

**Source:** [Send a SMS Text From A Link](http://thenewcode.com/856/Send-a-SMS-Text-From-A-Link)

As mentioned in the article the support depends on the platform and the SMS app, some work while others don't.

**Also avoid using it if there's no dynamic component involve for device detection; since on <del>desktop</del> older Operating Systems the link will do absolutely nothing.**

Comment: Does the multiple recipients work cross-platform? You add an example for iOS, does separating by ',' work also on Android?

Comment: Hi @Luciano, please see the source link which describes device support. The article is quite old so in my opinion it's best if you could check on each individual device and OS version.

Comment: btw the link to your small demo is broken

Comment: @Luciano, fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it does work on Windows 10! it opens the Messaging App

Comment: On a Mac (OS 10.14 at least), an SMS link opens Messages btw